# How to resolve ValueError while deploying Django project on IIS?

Tags: python, django, iis

On begining, i dont have experience in deploy on production, so please forgive my stupid question.
What i have done:

1. all steps from toturial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APCQ15YqqQ0&t=882s , it's call Default Web Site, and it works,
2. by analogy i deploy my project called SLK but on port 81 on second web site, and tree looks like this:

[image]

3. i change web.config for project SLK, moved it to main catalog C:\inetpub\wwwroot (at toturial was web.config maid for toturial project, i changed all entries for my project)
4. turn off Default Web Site, turn on my and got this masage on IIS, on localhost:81:
   [image]
5. When i start project manualy in 127.0.0.1:8000 on Debug mode it's works.

Please for sugestions and ideas

Django ver 3.2
Python ver 3.9
Windows 10

Comment: Could you please check if this [post](https://community.plotly.com/t/flask-windows-iis-plotly-dash-error-occured-while-reading-wsgi-handler/9911) is helpful to your problem ?

Comment: yes, i tried but not helped

Comment: I think the issue can be caused by a number of reasons. Since you can deploy the application(Default website site) and run it success, I think you need to check if there is any difference between the two. And please check if there is any mistake in your `web.config` when you change it.